# What is the equivalent Mac OS command to Ubuntu isosize command?

Tags: macos, iso-image

I want to output the length of an iso9660 filesystem in Mac OS terminal.

In linux (Ubuntu) the command is

```
isosize -d 2048 /dev/disk0
```

What is the equivalent command in Mac OS for that purpose and how to install it?